# How to reorder rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and would like to reorder the rows so that for example row 5 can be switched to row 2 and row 2 say to row 7. I have a list with all rownames delimited with `\n` and I thought I could somehow read it into R (its a txt file) and then just use the name of the matrix (in my case 'k' and do something like `k[txt file,]-> k_new`  but this does not work since the identifiers are not the first column but are defined as rownames.

Comment: You say columns in the title but rows in the text. Which is it?

Comment: Posting output of dput(k) should help clarify some the outstanding ambiguities in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
k[ c(1,5,3,4,7,6,2), ] #But probably not what you meant....
```

Or perhaps (if your 'k' object rownames are something other than the default character-numeric sequence):

```
k[ char_vec , ]   # where char_vec will get matched to the row names.

(dat <- structure(list(person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), time = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), income = c(100, 120, 150, 200, 90, 100, 
120, 150), disruption = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("person", 
"time", "income", "disruption"), row.names = c("h", "g", "f", 
"e", "d", "c", "b", "a"), class = "data.frame"))

 dat[ c('h', 'f', 'd', 'b') , ]
 #-------------
  person time income disruption
h      1    1    100          0
f      1    3    150          0
d      2    1     90          0
b      2    3    120          1
```

Comment: hallo - i was referring to rows - so if i have a list with the rownames in the correct sequence could i just use

k[txt file,] ?

Comment: I demonstrated how to rearrange rows. A character vector in the "i" position for "[" references rownames. (I will correct my second option which was misleading. You obviously could NOT use `k[txt file, ]` since there is a space between "txt" and "file" but if your object were named "txtfile" you could use `k[txtfile, ]`